# h:inputHidden in JSF composite component not submitted to a backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, codemirror, composite-component

I'm creating a JSF composite component based on a CodeMirror text editor and it's ['merge' addon](https://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html). Now my component is displayed as expected (basic editor plus an additional CodeMirror instance to compare with).

My code:

```
<cc:interface>
    <!-- attributes -->
    ...
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="..." name="..." />
    ...

    <h:outputScript library="..." name="..." />
    ...

    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <h:panelGroup id="pgContent" styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}" style="#{cc.attrs.style}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}">
            <h:inputHidden id="#{cc.clientId}_inputHiddenMain" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" immediate="true">
                <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.converter}">
                    <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.converter}" />
                </c:if>
            </h:inputHidden>
            <h:inputHidden id="#{cc.clientId}_inputHiddenLeft" value="#{cc.attrs.origLeft}" immediate="true" rendered="#{cc.attrs.origLeft ne null}">
                <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.converter}">
                    <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.converter}" />
                </c:if>
            </h:inputHidden>
            <h:inputHidden id="#{cc.clientId}_inputHiddenRight" value="#{cc.attrs.origRight}" immediate="true" rendered="#{cc.attrs.origRight ne null}">
                <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.converter}">
                    <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.converter}" />
                </c:if>
            </h:inputHidden>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        if(#{cc.attrs.rendered}){
            if (!com) {
                var com = {};
            }

            if (!com.example) {
                com = {
                    example: {}
                };
            }

            if (!com.example.faces) {
                com.example = {
                    faces: {}
                };
            }

            if (!com.example.faces.codemirrormerge) {
                com.example.faces.codemirrormerge = {
                    init: function(id, clientId, styleClass, ...) {

                        var cmmInput = $("[id='" + clientId + ":" + id + "_inputHiddenMain']"),
                            cmmOrigLeft = $("[id='" + clientId + ":" + id + "_inputHiddenLeft']"),
                            cmmOrigRight = $("[id='" + clientId + ":" + id + "_inputHiddenRight']"),
                            target = $('.' + styleClass),
                            options = {
                                    value: cmmInput.val(),
                                    revertButtons : revertButtons,
                                    showDifferences : showDifferences,
                                    connect : connect,
                                    collapseIdentical : collapseIdentical,
                                    mode: mode,
                                    theme: theme,
                                    autoRefresh: true,
                                    ...
                                },
                            myCodeMirrorMerge = CodeMirror.MergeView(target[0], options),
                            myCodeMirror = myCodeMirrorMerge.editor();

                            myCodeMirror.on("blur", function() {
                                $("[id='" + clientId + ":" + id + "_inputHiddenMain']").val(myCodeMirror.getValue());
                            });                    
                    }
                }
            }

            // init component
            com.example.faces.codemirrormerge.init('#{cc.attrs.id}', '#{cc.clientId}', '#{cc.attrs.styleClass}', ...);
        }
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
</cc:implementation>
```

I used three `inputHidden` components to hold an editor value and two values to compare with. When 'blur' event occurs, changes made in editor are copied back to an `inputHidden` component. So far so good. But when I use component like this:

```
<myns:codeMirrorMerge id="inputContent" styleClass="myStyleClass" origLeft="#{bean.origLeft}" origRight="#{bean.origRight}" value="#{bean.content}" converter="escapeConverter" mode="text/x-plsql" theme="eclipse"
                            matchBrackets="true" closeBrackets="true" activeLine="true" autocompleteSql="true" lineWrapping="true" />
<p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" action="#{bean.saveContent}" />
```

, `inputHidden` value with editor content should be submitted in a backing bean, but it isn't. I also tried with `process="@(.myStyleClass)"` to explicitly process the whole component, but no luck.

So my question is: Why is an `inputHidden` value not submitted in a backing bean?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this `id="#{cc.clientId}_inputHiddenMain"` really be this `id="#{cc.id}_inputHiddenMain"` for all your inputHiddens?

Comment: Totally missed that, thanks! You should write an answer to my question, could be useful for other users.